# Is a member initialization list without a value defined?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++20, member-initialization

Say I have :

```
class Foo
{
public:
  int x;
  Foo() : x() {}
}
```

Would it be UB to read `x` after the constructor has ran? More specifically, what type of initialization is this, zero, direct or default initialization?

I know if instead we'd have:

```
Foo() : x(42) {}
```

`x` would be direct-initialized to `42` but I'm not so sure for the snippet above and I don't want to get bit by the UB wolf if this turns out to be default-initialized.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: Isn't it a [zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) "*As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types that have no constructors, including value initialization of elements of aggregates for which no initializers are provided."* and *"If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T."*?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the duplicate, no clue why I didn't find one.

Comment: @HattedRooster No problem.  FWIW, I googled *what do empty parentheses mean in member initializer c++* to find it.  Target was the first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what type of initialization is this

`x()` performs [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> when a non-static data member or a base class is initialized using a member initializer with an empty pair of parentheses `or braces (since C++11)`;

As non-class type `int`, `x` is zero-initialized as `0` at last.

> 4. otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Comment: So a mem initializer list does not change the syntax and this will be value-initialized, I see.